# Creates a list from user input

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I feel like this should be an easy task but I can't seem to figure it out.
I have a question

```
Subject_List = []
Subject = input("Please enter a subject")
Subject_List.append(Subject)
```

(This isn't my code, just an example)
So this asks for a subject, then appends to into the list.
My question is: 
How do I make it so each 'subject' that the user enters is a separate list? If that makes sense. So for example.

```
Subject_List = []
Subject = input("Please enter a subject")
Subject_List.append(Subject) #Lets say the user English. Therefore Subject_List = [English]
```

But now I want to create a whole new list. For example.

```
Subject_List2 = []
Subject = input("Please enter a subject")
Subject_List2.append(Subject) #Lets say the user Math. Therefore Subject_List2 = [Math]
```

Usually, I could just define a few different lists and each time an input is entered it moves on but the user is going to be required to enter a lot. Is there a way I can automate the creation of a list?

Comment: Do you want to have many lists with the subject name as their only one element, or do you want the subject name to be the name of the new list?

Comment: Why are you creating new lists for each element

Comment: It is very hard to explain but I will do my best. I have a Tkinter Window. An entry box labeled 'Line(1)' and the user is asked to enter orange food. Then there is a button they can press, 'next' and then it is labeled 'Line(1)+1 so Line2. Asking the user to enter red food. Then if they press 'next' it is then labeled Line(2)+1 so Line3. And asked to enter blue food. I want my code to create a list each time a new "line" is created. So there would be a 'Line 1' list = Orange food, A 'line 2' list = Red food and a 'Line 3' list = Blue food.

Comment: You could use a dictionary "food": `food["orange"] = []`

Comment: You can use `exec` for this purpose, do let me know if you want an example

Answer (score 0):

Input result can be converted to the list as follows:

```
subject = [input("Please enter a subject")]
```

Or:

```
subject = [input("Please enter a subject")]
subject = [subject]
```